# Multiple representations of the same entity are being merged with @OneToMany

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I have a web application built with Spring Boot connected with a db PostgreSql, the project is about a education institute and manage Students and invoicing...

I generate manually all the invoices. I add the first cuota(invoice) normally but when i want to generate the second, i've this issue:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple representations of the same entity [com.codeboros.app.entity.Cuota#1] are being merged. Detached: [com.codeboros.app.entity.Cuota@1788e1df]; Managed: [com.codeboros.app.entity.Cuota@2697e3fc]
```

I've this entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ALUMNOS")
public class Alumno implements Serializable {           
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="alumno", cascade= {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.REMOVE,CascadeType.REFRESH,CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JsonIgnore 
    private List<Cuota> cuotas;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="Cuota")
public class Cuota extends Factura implements Serializable  {
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="alumno_cod")
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE) 
    Alumno alumno;
}
```

And the AlumnoController

```
@PostMapping("/alumnoGenCuota/{id}")    
public String GenCuota(@PathVariable Long id, Cuota cuota) {
    Alumno alumno = alumnoService.get(id);
    cuota.setAlumno(alumno);
    cuota.setMonto(alumno.getCurso().getCuota()); 
    cuota.setDetalle(alumno.getCurso().getNombre()+":  $"+alumno.getCurso().getCuota()); //detalle
    alumno.AgregarCuota(cuota);             

    alumnoService.save(alumno);

    return "redirect:/alumnocuotas/"+id;
}
```

I tried to remove CascadeType.MERGE but do not save the news Cuotas

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using Hibernate, remove `CascadeType.MERGE` from the entity that is not allowing you to persist the detached entity or put all cascade type other than `CascadeType.MERGE`

If you are using Hibernate, add the following lines to your persistence.xml -

```
<property name="hibernate.event.merge.entity_copy_observer" value="allow"/>
```

When you set `hibernate.event.merge.entity_copy_observer=allow`, Hibernate will merge each entity copy detected while cascading the merge operation. In the process of merging each entity copy, Hibernate will cascade the merge operation from each entity copy to its assocations with `cascade=CascadeType.MERGE` or `CascadeType.ALL`. The entity state resulting from merging an entity copy will be overwritten when another entity copy is merged.

Comment: add the property solved the error, but doesn't save the object

Comment: this could be a different issue ...have you updated the question?

Comment: Wouldn't one entity copy overriding another be an issue, potentially causing lost data?

Comment: In other words, how do you know that the right representation wins when saving to the database?